# When using fstream in a library I get linker errors in the executable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lnk2019, lnk2001

When I add

```
#include <fstream>
```

and try to use

```
std::ifstream (i.e. std::ifstream ifile(pDest))
```

in my library I get the following linker errors when compiling a project whih uses the library:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: wchar_t * & __thiscall std::vector<wchar_t *,class std::allocator<wchar_t *> >::operator[](unsigned int)" (??A?$vector@PA_WV?$allocator@PA_W@std@@@std@@QAEAAPA_WI@Z) C:\zipprojnotworking\CPP\7zip\UI\TestingZipper\Console.lib(ZipLib.obj)  TestingZipper
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW C:\zipprojnotworking\CPP\7zip\UI\TestingZipper\libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) TestingZipper
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg referenced in function "private: void __thiscall std::_Yarn<char>::_Tidy(void)" (?_Tidy@?$_Yarn@D@std@@AAEXXZ) C:\zipprojnotworking\CPP\7zip\UI\TestingZipper\Console.lib(ZipLib.obj)  TestingZipper
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg    C:\zipprojnotworking\CPP\7zip\UI\TestingZipper\libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) TestingZipper
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __free_dbg    C:\zipprojnotworking\CPP\7zip\UI\TestingZipper\libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj)    TestingZipper
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg referenced in function "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int,struct std::_DebugHeapTag_t const &,char *,int)" (??2@YAPAXIABU_DebugHeapTag_t@std@@PADH@Z) C:\zipprojnotworking\CPP\7zip\UI\TestingZipper\libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) TestingZipper
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg  C:\zipprojnotworking\CPP\7zip\UI\TestingZipper\libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj)    TestingZipper
Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __calloc_dbg referenced in function __Getctype    C:\zipprojnotworking\CPP\7zip\UI\TestingZipper\libcpmtd.lib(_tolower.obj)   TestingZipper Error 10  error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals   C:\zipprojnotworking\CPP\7zip\UI\Console\Debug\TestingZipper.exe    TestingZipper
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: When you add `#include` what?

Comment: It looks to me like you're linking to the wrong CRT. How did you create your project?

Answer (score 3):

5+ years later... the problem (and maybe many others) is already solved (and forgotten :) )

You have 1 *lib* project that contains the code above: I assume it's in a *.c(xx)* file and not in a *.h* file (included in both projects), and an *app* project that makes use of the previous one. 
I've thought about what could the configuration that would yield this behavior be (the *lib* project building fine and the *app* project having these *unresolved externals*) and the only configuration that stands up is: the *lib* project is not correct. Let me detail:

- One missing symbol is ***CrtDbgReport***, that tells me that the lib is built in *Debug* mode.
- The fact that the *lib* is building *OK*, tells me that either:

  1. The *lib* project is fine, and the error is in the *app* project
  2. The *lib* project is not fine (and the *app* project may or may not be fine) but it's a **static** library - and in this case the *.obj* files are simply "merged" together in the resulting *.lib* file
- it is **not linked** so the linker does not search for unresolved externals at this point and it will only search when this library will be linked in an executable (*.exe* or *.dll*). This is backed out by the fact that I saw *libcpmtd.lib*<sup>***(1)***</sup> in the error log: using the static **runtime library ((U)CRT)** version (especially in a project that contains libraries) only makes sense when building a static *app* (usually designed to run in a *stripped out* environment - e.g. on a "*Windows minimalistic core*" distribution where it could only need core libraries like: *ntdll.dll*, *kernel32.dll*, ...).
- The fact that there were no duplicate symbols at link time (*app* project) rules out the 1<sup>st option.</sup>

This is better that we can simplify the environment required for reproducing the behavior. You can switch *Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type* and change from *Static Library (.lib)* to *Dynamic Library (.dll)*. Now, at the end it will link and will fail spitting the errors when building the *lib* project.

<sup>***1***</sup> Check [[SO]: Errors when linking to protobuf 3 on MS Visual C (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118400/4788546) for details about the CRT linking types (check the links as well). Also check [[SO]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546) for more details about what happens when building *C* and *C++* code.

A few words about [[MS.Learn]: Debug vs Release](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xiangfan/2008/08/30/debug-vs-release) builds: when building in *Debug* mode, some instrumentation code is silently added in your code to facilitate debugging. That's why *Debug* build artifacts (*vs* their *Release* counterparts):

- Have significantly larger size
- Run slower

The code addition is typically achieved by differences between build steps (simplified version):

- *Preprocess*: the ***_DEBUG*** macro is defined (as opposed to *Release* where ***NDEBUG*** is defined). You can browse standard include files and you'll see lots of preprocessor directives (***#ifdef***s mostly) on these macros. This phase has a direct impact on compile phase
- *Link*: the right libraries (that actually contain that instrumentation code) are chosen

The most important thing is that the compile (and indirectly, preprocess) and link phases **must be in sync**. This is not the case for your *lib* project, so you have an *UCRT* mismatch (as the 3rd comment states). To fix this, **either**:

- Change the ***_DEBUG*** / ***NDEBUG*** macro definition from: *Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions*
- Change *UCRT* type from: *Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library*

I listed them both, since I don't know which one is incorrect (as you would want the configuration settings to match the configuration name (*Debug* / *Release*)), but I have a feeling that it's the latter.

Also, make sure to have consistent settings across projects that are supposed to work together.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone like me that this answer did not ring helpful, a second option is to go to:
**Project Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Project Defaults->.NET Target Framework Version** and set it to **v4.0**

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/806238/unwarranted-linker-errors-using-stl-filestream-class-in-managed-classes-in-c-11-cli has an obscure answer from Microsoft team that fixed my issue.

I also added this answer to another version of the same problem.