# C++ dll export undefined

Tags: c++, dllexport

I am trying to create a C++ DLL that I can import in c#, but my code won't compile.

Here is the code:

```
//main.cpp
#include "C:\Users\Mihai\Desktop\body.cpp"
#include "C:\Users\Mihai\Desktop\header.h"

extern "C"_declspec(dllexport) int sumTwo(int var_x, int var_y)
{
    myClass MC(var_x, var_y);
    return MC.sumX_Y();

}

//body.cpp
#pragma once
#include "Header.h"

myClass::myClass(int var_x, int var_y)
{
    x = var_x;
    y = var_y;
}

int myClass::sumX_Y()
{
    return x + y;
}

//Header.h
#pragma once

class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(int var_x, int var_y);
    int sumX_Y();
private:
    int x;
    int y;

};

/*
```

Here are the errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0130   expected a '{'  SumadllptCsharp e:\work\Info\SumadllptCsharp\SumadllptCsharp\main.cpp   4  
Error (active)  E0040   expected an identifier  SumadllptCsharp e:\work\Info\SumadllptCsharp\SumadllptCsharp\main.cpp   4  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "dllexport" is undefined SumadllptCsharp e:\work\Info\SumadllptCsharp\SumadllptCsharp\main.cpp   4  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "var_x" is undefined SumadllptCsharp e:\work\Info\SumadllptCsharp\SumadllptCsharp\main.cpp   6  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "var_y" is undefined SumadllptCsharp e:\work\Info\SumadllptCsharp\SumadllptCsharp\main.cpp   6  
Error   C3690   expected a string literal, but found a user-defined string literal instead  SumadllptCsharp e:\work\info\sumadllptcsharp\sumadllptcsharp\main.cpp   4  
Error   C2144   syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'   SumadllptCsharp e:\work\info\sumadllptcsharp\sumadllptcsharp\main.cpp   4  
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    SumadllptCsharp e:\work\info\sumadllptcsharp\sumadllptcsharp\main.cpp   4
```

Comment: ok, sorry i wasn't able to put the code here because iti did not work. Some nice guy helped me by editing my post.

Comment: `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)` (at least this is one). And `sumTwo` is part of _main.cpp_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your updated code:

- *DummyClass.h*

  ```cpp
  #pragma once


  class DummyClass {
    public:
      DummyClass(int var_x, int var_y);
      int sumX_Y();

    private:
      int x;
      int y;
  };
  ```
- *DummyClass.cpp*

  ```cpp
  #include "DummyClass.h"


  DummyClass::DummyClass(int var_x, int var_y)
  {
      x = var_x;
      y = var_y;
  }


  int DummyClass::sumX_Y()
  {
      return x + y;
  }
  ```
- *header.h*:

  ```c
  #pragma once

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  if defined(Q047496315_STATIC)
  #    define Q047496315_EXPORT_API
  #  else
  #    if defined(Q047496315_EXPORTS)
  #      define Q047496315_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #    else
  #      define Q047496315_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #    endif
  #  endif
  #else
  #  define Q047496315_EXPORT_API
  #endif

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  Q047496315_EXPORT_API int sumTwo(int var_x, int var_y);

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  }
  #endif
  ```
- *main.cpp*

  ```cpp
  #define Q047496315_EXPORTS
  #include "header.h"
  #include "DummyClass.h"


  int sumTwo(int var_x, int var_y)
  {
      DummyClass dc(var_x, var_y);
      return dc.sumX_Y();
  }
  ```

**Notes**:

- There were 2 major problems with your code:

  - The class definition wasn't complete: missing `};` at the end of *header.h* (don't know whether this isn't a copy/paste issue)
  - The `extern "C"_declspec(dllexport)`, as I specified in my comment
- Other than that, I did some other non critical corrections. Please take a look at the differences between your code and mine

  - Rename the class: personally I hate stuff names starting with *My*, it tells me that their purpose is not clear in creators' mind
  - Reorganize the files:

    - The class is in its own 2 files now
    - split *main.cpp* in 2 (and use *header.h* as one of them) in order for the project to be usable from *C* / *C++* (although you said you only need it from *C#*)

**Output** (build from *VStudio 2015 Community*):

> ```
> 1>------ Build started: Project: q47496315, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
> 1>  main.cpp
> 1>  DummyClass.cpp
> 1>  Generating Code...
> 1>  q47496315.vcxproj -> C:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q47496315\Win32-Debug\q47496315.dll
> 1>  q47496315.vcxproj -> C:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q47496315\Win32-Debug\q47496315.pdb (Full PDB)
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
> ```

Here's also a (partial) image of the *.dll* loaded in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com), showing that the function is being exported:

[image: img0]

References (that might be useful):

- [[SO]: Linker error when calling a C function from C++ code in different VS2010 project (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30583411/4788546)
- [[SO]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546)
- [[SO]: Errors when linking to protobuf 3 on MS Visual C (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118400/4788546)
- [[SO]: When using fstream in a library I get linker errors in the executable (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41558269/4788546)
- [[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546)

*Noroc!*

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Mersi