# Calling Python function with parameters from C++ project (Visual Studio)

Tags: python, c++

I need to call a pipeline realized as a Python (3.6) function from my C++ project under the Windows platform. Function “**function_name**” from file  "**experiment_test.py**" takes text string as input parameter and return another text string as the result. I try the code below but it doesn’t work properly – python functions from libraries **shutil**, **codecs**, **makedirs**, etc doesn’t work.

C++ code (reduced):

```
std::string Text,Result;
PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;
Py_Initialize();

pName = PyUnicode_FromString("experiment_test");
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);    
pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "function_name");

pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
pValue = PyUnicode_FromString(Text.c_str());
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);

if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
{
    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    if (pValue != NULL)
    {
        Result = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(pValue);    
        Py_DECREF(pValue);
    }
    else return false;    
}
// ...

Py_Finalize();
```

Python code (reduced):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import shutil
import codecs
from os import makedirs
from os import path
from os import unlink
from subprocess import call

def function_name():

    name = 'working_files/current_text'

    if not path.exists('working_files'):
        makedirs('working_files')
    if path.exists('result.txt'):
        unlink('result.txt')
    with codecs.open(name + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(text)
    # ...
    return result
```

So no new files will be generated by Python. I tried to import Python modules in C++ by calling **PyRun_SimpleString("import shutil");** etc after **Py_Initialize();** but it doesn’t help.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: What **exactly** doesn't work (error, traceback, etc)? Did you try running the _Python_ module directly (without adding the _C++_ layer)? Note that your code is syntactically incorrect (indentation-wise).

Comment: Python functions from shutil, codecs, makedirs doesn't work when  “function_name” is called from C++. If I call Python module from the command line, it works correctly. No errors occur - C++ receive the result which is equal to input. Python function should write input string into the text file, process this file and then read the result and return it back. Indentation in my code is correct, unfortunately I did a mistake when I wrote it here, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried replicating the problem with the given intel, but it was impossible, so I created a small example (as close as possible to what's described in the question) - Also referred to as [[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (that should be included in the question *BTW*)

So, the problem that I'm illustrating here, is:

- *C++*

  - Load the *Python* engine
  - Load a *Python* module
  - From that module, load a function which:

    - Receives a (string) argument representing a file name
    - Reads the file contents (text) and returns it
    - In case of error, simply returns the file name
  - Call that function
  - Get the function call result

I am using (on *Win 10 x64 (10.0.16299.125)*):

- *Python **3.5.4** x64*
- *VStudio 2015 Community Edition*

The structure consists of:

- *VStudio* project / solution

  - Source file (*main00.cpp* (**renamed it** from *main.cpp*, but didn't feel like doing all the screenshots (containing it) all over again))
- *Python* module (*experiment_test.py*)
- Test file (*test_file.txt*)

*main00.cpp*:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#if defined(_DEBUG)
#  undef _DEBUG
#  define _DEBUG_UNDEFINED
#endif
#include <Python.h>
#if defined(_DEBUG_UNDEFINED)
#  define _DEBUG
#  undef _DEBUG_UNDEFINED
#endif

#define MOD_NAME "experiment_test"
#define FUNC_NAME "function_name"
#define TEST_FILE_NAME "..\\test_dir\\test_file.txt"

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;


int cleanup(const string &text = string(), int exitCode = 1) {
    Py_Finalize();
    if (!text.empty())
        cout << text << endl;
    cout << "Press ENTER to return...\n";
    cin.get();
    return exitCode;
}


int main() {
    string fName = TEST_FILE_NAME, result;
    PyObject *pName = NULL, *pModule = NULL, *pDict = NULL, *pFunc = NULL, *pArgs = NULL, *pValue = NULL, *pResult = NULL;
    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString(MOD_NAME);
    if (pName == NULL) {
        return cleanup("PyUnicode_FromString returned NULL");
    }
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    if (pModule == NULL) {
        return cleanup(string("NULL module: '") + MOD_NAME + "'");
    }
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    if (pDict == NULL) {
        return cleanup("NULL module dict");
    }
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, FUNC_NAME);
    if (pFunc == NULL) {
        return cleanup(string("module '") + MOD_NAME + "' doesn't export func '" + FUNC_NAME + "'");
    }
    pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
    if (pArgs == NULL) {
        return cleanup("NULL tuple returned");
    }
    pValue = PyUnicode_FromString(fName.c_str());
    if (pValue == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        return cleanup("PyUnicode_FromString(2) returned NULL");
    }
    int setItemResult = PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
    if (setItemResult) {
        Py_DECREF(pValue);
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        return cleanup("PyTuple_SetItem returned " + setItemResult);
    }
    pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    if (pResult == NULL) {
        return cleanup("PyObject_CallObject returned NULL");
    } else {
        int len = ((PyASCIIObject *)(pResult))->length;
        char *res = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(pResult);
        Py_DECREF(pResult);
        if (res == NULL) {
            return cleanup("PyUnicode_AsUTF8 returned NULL");
        } else {
            cout << string("C(++) - Python call: ") << MOD_NAME << "." << FUNC_NAME << "('" << fName << "') returned '" << res << "' (len: " << len << ")" << endl;
        }
    }
    return cleanup("OK", 0);
}
```

**Notes**:

- The *_DEBUG* / *_DEBUG_UNDEFINED* stuff at the beginning - a (lame) workaround (*gainarie*) to link against *Release* *Python* lib (*python35.lib*) when building in *Debug* mode (as opposed to *python35_**d**.lib*) - read below
- As I said, tried to simplify the code (got rid of the *PyCallable_Check* test)
- It's easily noticeable that the code is written in ***C*** style, although it uses the ***C++*** compiler
- Since *Python API* ([[Python.Docs]: Embedding Python in Another Application](https://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html)) (both extending / embedding) uses pointers, make sure to **test for *NULL*s**, otherwise there's a high chance getting *SegFault* (*Access Violation*)
- Added the [[Python.Docs]: Reference Counting - void Py_DECREF(PyObject *o)](https://docs.python.org/c-api/refcounting.html#c.Py_DECREF) statements to avoid memory leaks
- Build (compile / link) / Run options (obviously, you got past these, since you were able to run your program, but I'm going to list them anyway - for sure there are some shortcuts here, when dealing with **more than one** such project):

  - Check [[SO]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546) for details building a *Win PE*
  - To speed-up process when building projects that depend on *Python*, I created a *VStudio User Macro* (called e.g. *Python35Dir* - like in the image below, pointing to my *Python 3.5* installation *dir*)

  [image: macros]

  **Notes**:

  - The path ("*c:\Install\x64\Python\Python\3.5*") points to the installation downloaded from the official site
  - Obviously, for *032bit*, the path must be set accordingly (to *32bit* *Python*)
  - This path contains (as expected) a *Release* version, and this is fine as long as I don't need to get into *Python* code (and as long as I don't mess around with memory - as (when building my app in *Debug* mode) I have 2 *C runtimes* in my *.exe* - check the links below to see what happens when tampering with *MSVC runtimes* (*UCRT*s)):

    - [[SO]: When using fstream in a library I get linker errors in the executable (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41558269/4788546)
    - [[SO]: Errors when linking to protobuf 3 on MS Visual C (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118400/4788546)
    - For *exceptional* cases, I have built *Python* in *Debug* mode and got the binaries, but that's not my 1<sup>st</sup> choice, since it requires settings (paths) changes
  - Compile:

    Let *VStudio* know about the *Python* include files location:

    [image: include]
  - Link:

    Let *VStudio* know about the *Python* lib files location (if only *pythonxx*.lib* (***PYTHONCORE***) is required, nothing extra needed, since *PYTHONCORE* is included by default by *Python* code; otherwise, all the rest should be specified in the [[MS.Learn]: .Lib Files as Linker Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dot-lib-files-as-linker-input):

    [image: link]
  - Run / Debug - let:

    - *VStudio* know where *Python* runtime ***python35.dll*** (*PYTHONCORE*) is located (*%PATH%*)
    - Loaded *Python* runtime know where additional modules are located (*%PYTHONPATH%*)

    [image: debug]

*experiment_test.py*:

```py
import codecs
import os
import shutil


def function_name(file_name):
    print("Py - arg: '{:s}'".format(file_name))
    if not os.path.isfile(file_name):
        return file_name
    with open(file_name, mode="rb") as f:
        content = f.read().decode()
        print("Py - Content len: {:d}, Content (can spread across multiple lines): '{:s}'".format(len(content), content))
        return content
```

**Notes**:

- An almost dummy module, as specified at the beginning
- Works **only with *text* files** (*decode* will fail for *binary* files)
- Imports modules that aren't used, to see that they are OK (that's obvious, if one such *import* statement succeeds, all should)
- Prints some data on *stdout* (to be matched with what's on the *C++* side)
- Located in a path **known by *Python*** (*%PYTHONPATH%* from previous step)
- Has 1 argument (*file_name*) - **crucial difference** compared to the one in the question which doesn't have any (don't know whether that's a logical mistake or a *typo* like one)

*test_dir\test_file.txt*:

```
line 0 - dummy
line 1 - gainarie
```

**Output** (*VStudio* console):

> ```bat
> Py - arg: 'test_dir\test_file.txt'
> Py - Content len: 33, Content (can spread across multiple lines): 'line 0 - dummy
> line 1 - gainarie'
> C(++) - Python call: experiment_test.function_name('test_dir\test_file.txt') returned 'line 0 - dummy
> line 1 - gainarie' (len: 33)
> OK
> Press ENTER to return...
> ```

**Final note**:

- In this case (the simple one), *PYTHONCORE* from installation path was used. But in other ones (*e.g.* shipped in another product), ***Python*'s standard library path must be set before *Py_Initialize*, via *Py_SetPythonHome***. 
  Although it's old, [[SO]: What files are required for Py_Initialize to run? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39541474/4788546) might contain some useful info

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Im' trying to use it with my code, but the python module fails to load today. I think, I will try to use your code on my machine if I'll not find my error.

Comment: Did you have a chance to test (it's not just the code but also the build process)? If you still have issues executing the *Python* code, wrap all the code from *experiment\_test.py* in a `try/except` clause and print the exception.

Comment: Sorry for keep you waiting - my code doesn't work at the time.

Comment: It's really interesting now with build process differences. Today I started to rebuild your solution (with my software versions) - but if I write "$(PythonDir)\libs" in Additional dependencies, I get link error. At the time I stopped with "$(PythonDir)\libs\python36.lib" and will continue a little later. I will write about the result.

Comment: But you set *$(PythonDir)* under *User Macros* for the correct architecture(s) pointing to the right path(s), right?

Comment: Yes, macro _$(PythonDir)_ points to the Python directory, as in your example.

Comment: Check the correctness of the path (I'm not sure if this could generate a problem, but also check the *bkslash*es especially those at the end). Also make sure to build in *Release* mode (check the 1st code related Notes). Then you could edit the question and add the link error and also the *Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Command Line* for the *Configuration/Platform* pair you're trying to build.

Comment: It's working now (_Debug_ to the surprise), I need some time for analysis, I'll write a description a little later. Thank you!! It seems that there were several problems - one of them was with paths.

Comment: Yes, working fine, thank you very much! It seems that my problem was with paths - my C++ program didn't see my python module, my python script didn't see Python home directory AND it didn't see the external modules it wanted to use (some ready exe-modules). So I need the correction of PATH, PYTHONPATH and WORKING_DIR. Both _Debug_ and _Release_ versions are working without any additional difficulties.

Comment: Smth like in the last image that I posted? If this answers your question, please mark it as such.

Comment: Actually, I used your advices with my application - finally the pipeline start working fine. Previously it couldn't save input data or process it in the right way. Unfortunately, I can't mark your post as an answer right now - my ratio is too low at the moment(