# How to return value from DLL using parameter of function as a pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, dll, return-value, dllexport

I have a simple DLL:

dllmain.cpp:

```
#define MYDLLDIR        
#include "pch.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    ...
}


void callByPtr(int *i) {
    
    (*i)++;
}
```

pch.h

```
#include "framework.h"

#ifdef MYDLLDIR
#define DLLDIR __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall
#else
#define DLLDIR __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {

    DLLDIR void callByPtr(int *i);
        
};
```

Client:

```
typedef void(__stdcall* callByPtr)(int*);

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hDLL;

    hDLL = LoadLibrary(_T("MyDll.dll"));

    if (NULL != hDLL)
    {

        callByPtr myCall = (callByPtr)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "callByPtr");

        if (!myCall) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        int i = 10;

        int* ptri = &i;

        std::cout << "i " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ptri " << ptri << std::endl;

        myCall(ptri);

        std::cout << "---- After Call ----\n";

        std::cout << "i " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ptri " << ptri << std::endl;    

    }
}
```

Result:

---- Before Call ----

i = 10

ptri = 0025FB40

---- After Call ----

i = 11286192

ptri = 0025FB3C

The adress of ptri has changed and value was not 11.

How to implement this properly that I can get a value from DLL using method above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exporting definitions are also not correct. Should be something like:

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORT
#define MYDLLDIR  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLLDIR __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

and use the same macro (MYDLLDIR) for both export (dll, #MYDLL_EXPORT defined) and import(clients, #MYDLL_EXPORT NOT defined)

You have to use the same calling convention for callByPtr in all places, in your case
__stdcall (the default one is __cstdcall).

In your pch.h then:

```
MYDLLDIR void __stdcall callByPtr(int *i);
```

Comment: But I'm not using the "import"

Comment: you do use DLLDIR void callByPtr(int *i); in your pch.h. This is not correct. See my edit

Comment: I'm so sorry it was my typo, now I edited it but it does not help

Comment: as suggested by other user -> remove __stdcall completely or place it after return type

Answer (score 0):

since you return void in your exported function DLLDIR void callByPtr(int *i); you should use the default calling convention for C and C++ programs __cdecl.
After changing:

1. in your pch.h file:
   #define DLLDIR __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall
   to
   #define DLLDIR __declspec(dllexport)
2. in your Client file:
   typedef void(__stdcall* callByPtr)(int*);
   to
   typedef void(__cdecl* callByPtr)(int*);

The rebuild is without errors and warnings and the output is like that:
i 10 
ptri 0113FCA4
---- After Call ----
i 11
ptri 0113FCA4

Comment: What if I want to return let say "int" shall I use __stdcall?

Comment: No, sorry to put it wrong, you can also use __cdecl, or as @CristiFati mentioned use the default.

Answer (score 0):

According to [[MS.Docs]: __stdcall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall)

> #### Syntax
>
> > *return-type* **`__stdcall`** *function-name*[( *argument-list* )]

the calling convention specifier comes **after** the function return type. The way you defined it is **before**, so (probably) the compiler ignored it<sup>**???**</sup>, ending up in the *.dll* exporting the function as *__cdecl* (default), and when the *.exe* called it as *__stdcall*, **Bang! -> *Stack Corruption***, and what you think is your pointer is actually something completely different, hence your weird outputs. 
 **The thing that is interesting is that on my end, the compiler (*VS2017*) spits `error C2062: type 'void' unexpected` when I try to build the *.dll* using your form** (`#define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall`).

Below is **a working** example (I modified the file names and contents).

*dll00.h*:

```cpp
#pragma once

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if defined(DLL00_EXPORTS)
#    define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif

#if defined(CALL_CONV_STDCALL)
#  define CALL_CONV __stdcall
#else
#  define CALL_CONV
#endif

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API void CALL_CONV callByPtr(int *pI);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

*dll00.cpp*:

```cpp
#define DLL00_EXPORTS
#include "dll00.h"


void CALL_CONV callByPtr(int *pI) {
    if (pI) {
        (*pI)++;
    }
}
```

*main00.cpp*:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "dll00.h"

#if defined(CALL_CONV_STDCALL)
#  define FUNC_NAME "_callByPtr@4"
#else
#  define FUNC_NAME "callByPtr"
#endif

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


typedef void(CALL_CONV *CallByPtrFunc)(int*);


int main() {
    HMODULE hDLL;

    hDLL = LoadLibrary("dll00.dll");

    if (!hDLL) {
        std::cout << "LoadLibrary failed" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    CallByPtrFunc callByPtr = (CallByPtrFunc)GetProcAddress(hDLL, FUNC_NAME);

    if (!callByPtr) {
        std::cout << "GetProcAddress failed" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hDLL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int i = 10;

    int *ptri = &i;

    std::cout << "i " << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ptri " << ptri << std::endl;

    callByPtr(ptri);

    std::cout << "---- After Call ----\n";

    std::cout << "i " << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ptri " << ptri << std::endl;

    CloseHandle(hDLL);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q063951075]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86
> **********************************************************************
> ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.27
> ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> **********************************************************************
> [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86'
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> dll00.cpp
> dll00.h
> main00.cpp
>
> [prompt]> :: Build the .dll (passing /DCALL_CONV_STDCALL)
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL /DCALL_CONV_STDCALL dll00.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
> dll00.cpp
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Build the .exe (also passing /DCALL_CONV_STDCALL)
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /W0 /EHsc /DCALL_CONV_STDCALL main00.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /OUT:main00.exe
> main00.cpp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> dll00.cpp
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.h
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
> main00.cpp
> main00.exe
> main00.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> main00.exe
> i 10
> ptri 00F5FCC8
> ---- After Call ----
> i 11
> ptri 00F5FCC8
>
> [prompt]> :: It worked !!!
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dumpbin /EXPORTS dll00.dll
> Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.16.27043.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
>
> Dump of file dll00.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
>   Section contains the following exports for dll00.dll
>
>     00000000 characteristics
>     FFFFFFFF time date stamp
>         0.00 version
>            1 ordinal base
>            1 number of functions
>            1 number of names
>
>     ordinal hint RVA      name
>
>           1    0 00001000 _callByPtr@4
>
>   Summary
>
>         1000 .data
>         1000 .rdata
>         1000 .reloc
>         1000 .text
> ```

**Notes**:

- Obviously, **the code presented is not the one generating your output**:

  - It doesn't compile:

    - The error I mentioned at the beginning (although that could probably be avoided using some older compiler (or (doubtfully?) a compiler flag))
    - Missing ***#include***s and ***using***s in your *.exe* code
- "Minor" code problems:

  - *NULL* pointer test before dereferencing
  - *CloseHandle*
  - Differences between *DLLDIR* definition (as also mentioned by @Petr_Dokoupil): `__declspec(dllexport) __stdcall` *vs.* `__declspec(dllimport)`, but since you're dynamically loading the *.dll* instead of linking to it, **it has nothing to do with the error**
- Why the need to use *__stdcall*? (answer provided in comment: "*to be compatible with other languages*"):

  - It **only matters on *32bit*** (on *64bit* it's ignored)
  - It introduces a lot of additional issues (some of them you didn't even experienced), like the function name mangling (check *dumpbin* output), which can only be avoided using a *.def* file
  - All in all, this seems like an *XY Problem*. **You should use defaults** (get rid of *__stdcall* completely):

    - With this version of the code, simply don't pass ***/DCALL_CONV_STDCALL*** argument to the compiler when building the *.dll* and *.exe*
    - You're less likely to run into (subtle) problems (at least until you get more experience in this area)
    - Removing all the calling convention related code, would make it much shorter and cleaner
  - All the listed languages (*Delphi*, *Python*, *C#*, ...) have support for *__cdecl* (after all, I think that most of machine code running out there, is still written in *C*)

For more details regarding this whole area, you could check (including (recursively) referenced *URL*s):

- [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187566/python-ctypes-loading-dll-throws-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win/57297745#57297745)
- [[SO]: When using fstream in a library I get linker errors in the executable (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528437/when-using-fstream-in-a-library-i-get-linker-errors-in-the-executable/41558269#41558269)

Comment: Very useful notes, thank you! I was considering to use __stdcall to be compatible with other languages.

Comment: What other languages? In *C#* for example, you can specify the (unmanaged function) calling convention. Anyway, as I shown, it **is** possible to use *\_\_stdcall*, but it's a bit more tricky.

Comment: Other languages: Delphi/Pascal/C++ Builder, Python etc